# how can I extract item from row to another one with bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Is it possible to have a grid like the first one on desktop moving to the second one on mobile with bootstrap4 or, else, with pure css flex classes ?

Desktop view:

[image]

Mobile view :

[image]

For the moment my solution is the following one, but I do not like to repeat green content in two places. Can I avoid that please ?

```
<div class="container">
<main class="row">
    <section class="col-lg-8 ecran">
        <div class="row mes-contrats justify-content-around">
            <div class="col-12">
                lot's of content in red container
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row infos justify-content-around d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="col-12">
                lot's of content in green container
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="col-lg-4 asides">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                lot's of content in blue container
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 d-block d-lg-none">
                lot's of content in green container
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This can easily be done using CSS grid.

Comment: @m4n0 yes I know but my website must be compliant with IE11 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not pure bootstrap because to achieve the solution I used the position absolute and bootstrap does not have the mobile breakpoints on the `position-absolute` utility.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <style>
        .cnt-red { border: 5px solid red; }
        .cnt-blue { border: 5px solid blue; }
        .cnt-green { border: 5px solid green; }

        @media (min-width: 576px) {
            .cnt-left { width: 75%; }
            .cnt-right { width: 25%; right: 0; top:0; position: absolute; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
        <div class="p-2 cnt-left flex-grow-1 cnt-red flex-fill">Flex item 1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cnt-right cnt-blue flex-fill">Flex item 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit... </div>
        <div class="p-2 cnt-left cnt-green flex-fill">Flex item 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```